# Run npm commands after a deployment

Tags: api, deployment

I have recently deployed an api onto Railway, which works in a similar way to Heroku.

The deployment was successful.

The API returns a list of repositories, which I intend to connect with a React-Native app on the frontend.

Although the deploy was successful, in order for there to be any repositories on the API, I need to run a npm seed:run command which populates the API with some data.

In development, you just run npm seed:run.

How do you do this command in production after the API has been already deployed ?

Answer (score 0):

Railway exposes a command to allow you to run your scripts to be applied to your deployed application:

```
railway run <cmd>
```

In your case, this would look like:

```
railway run npm seed:run
```

Here is the railway documentation on railway commands:
https://docs.railway.app/develop/cli

Comment: This actually runs your local code with your Railway environment variables and not  the deployed code